# Subtract a str column from a datetime column

Tags: string, pandas, datetime

We can't subtract our time column from the current time column, because they have a different format:**Y-d-m HMS and Y-m-d HMS**. We cannot change the order in which we read in our time column. So we have to change the timeformat of our current column and make it as a datetime-object.

We tried `pd.to_datetime(df['Our time column'])`, however this puts the current column in the same order: `ex: 2019-05-08 05:58:00`

```
df['lenghtofstay']= (df['Current time']-df['Our time column'])
df['lenghtofstay'].head()
```

**Wrong answer**:
`98 days 07:50:02.393562`

**Current time**: 2019-08-14 13:54:40.303740

**Our time column**: 05-08-2019 05:58

**Current time -Our time column**: New column: 9 days xx:xx:xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all values in column `Our time column` have format `Y-d-m H:M:S` you can specify it by `format` parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Current time':['2019-08-14 13:54:40.303740','2019-05-10 05:58:00'],
                   'Our time column':['2019-05-08 05:58:00','2019-06-04 05:58:00']})

df['Current time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Current time'],)
df['Our time column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Our time column'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')

df['lenghtofstay']= (df['Current time']-df['Our time column'])
print (df)
                Current time     Our time column           lenghtofstay
0 2019-08-14 13:54:40.303740 2019-08-05 05:58:00 9 days 07:56:40.303740
1 2019-05-10 05:58:00.000000 2019-04-06 05:58:00       34 days 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The format of 'Our time column' date is:                                                                                        05-08-2019 05:58                                                                                                                     
Name: Our time column, dtype: object,                                                                              And format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M, unfortunately, does not work. What do I have to do to change this format into a working one

Comment: time data ' 05-08-2019 05:58' does not match format '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M'

Comment: oops, sorry - `format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')` or if first days ` `format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')` or try parameter `dayfirst=True` instaed `format`

Answer (score 0):

Do `pd.to_datetime()` twice to get both column in the same format

```
df['Current time']= pd.to_datetime(df['Current time'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
df['Current time']= pd.to_datetime(df['Current time'],format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
```

Then you can do the difference calculation